# Accessing element of array of pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am having some troubles with member function pointers. How do I fix this, and why doesn't this work? The issue is inside `main()`... or so I am guessing!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
using FnctPtr = void(T::*)(); // pointer to member function returning void

class Base {    
public:
    Base() : vtable_ptr{ &virtual_table[0] } {}
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "Base";
    }
    void x() { 
        std::cout << "X";
    }

 
private:
    // array of pointer to member function returning void
    inline static FnctPtr<Base> virtual_table[2] = { &Base::foo, &Base::x };

public:
    FnctPtr<Base>* vtable_ptr;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        vtable_ptr = reinterpret_cast<FnctPtr<Base>*>(&virtual_table[0]);
    }
    void foo() /* override */ {
        std::cout << "Derived";
    }

public:
    inline static FnctPtr<Derived> virtual_table[2] = { &Derived::foo, &Base::x };
};

int main() {
    Base* base = new Base();
    base->vtable_ptr[0](); // Issue here
    delete base;
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Why is `Derived` in the example? You are not using it.

Comment: @user17732522 yeah I realized that. But nonetheless, there's this error that I can't fix: `error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘* base->Base::vtable_ptr (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* * base->Base::......`

Comment: The error message is telling you what the correct syntax is...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I didn't make it work. I guess I got confused a bit. By the way, I believe the reinterpret_cast here should be fine. I'm not at all sure and I'll look again just to make sure...

Comment: No, it should be a `static_cast`, not a `reinterpret_cast`. The `reinterpret_cast`ed pointer would need to be cast back to the original type before use. With `static_cast` it is ok, but you have to make sure that the pointer is never called on an object which is not actually a `Derived`.

Comment: I'm confused. Aren't Derived and Base considered "similar" by the strict aliasing rules here?

Comment: No, they are not _similar_ in the sense of the strict aliasing rule, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing. But that isn't the point anyway. When using `reinterpret_cast` on a member pointer it behaves similar to `reinterpret_cast` on function pointers. The only thing the result is good for is casting back to the original type. See 10) in the link above. `static_cast` is required because the upcast may require adjustment of the pointer's value. Similar to how pointers to class objects cannot be downcast with `reinterpret_cast` safely.

Comment: Could you show an example with static_cast here? I can't seem to make it work with it.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize you are casting a pointer to a member pointer. My explanation above about the `reinterpret_cast` behavior isn't really correct then. But still, the `reinterpret_cast` here doesn't work, however the reason is not 10) from the link, but instead that there is no object of the target member pointer type that could be pointer-interconvertible with the original member pointer object. You need to make sure the arrays are of the same type (i.e. `FnctPtr<Base>`). Already cast the elements to that type with `static_cast` when creating the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `vtable_ptr` is `void (Base::**)()` while the type of `base->vtable_ptr[0]` is `void (Base::*)()`. The syntax that you're using for the call is incorrect.

> How do I fix this

The correct syntax of using the *pointer to member function* `void (Base::*)()` in your example would be as shown below:

```
(base->*(base->vtable_ptr[0]))();
```

Note that there was no need for the `Derived` class in the minimal reproducible example that you've provided.

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gCPJUq7lL)

Comment: Woah this is SO tricky! It works like a charm, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, once you understand that we're using pointer to members and so we must use `->*`(in case of pointer) or `.*` (in case of object) then it is easy to fine IMO. You're welcome.

Comment: The inner parentheses are optional and `vtable_ptr[0]` could be replaced with `*vtable_ptr` (both equally fine) and then the syntax is exactly what the compiler's error message is suggesting as well.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, they are optional. I like parenthesizing the expression wherever i can to be more explicit. So that the next time i read that these kind of long expressions, i don't have to think much about what is going on again. Its a personal preference.